# Using Bluetooth with Haxe NME

Tags: android, ios, haxe, nme

I was planning to use Haxe NME to develop a simple bluetooth chat application.

Is it possible to use device specific native APIs with Haxe? Or is there some wrapper class available to use bluetooth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The barrier to entry to using Bluetooth protocols is fairly high and is not a commonly used method to communicate easily for a chat application cross-platform. 
For example see this comparison chart of frameworks not supporting bluetooth;
http://www.markus-falk.com/mobile-frameworks-comparison-chart/

What is more commonly used is socket network connections, you can see a sample of a chat application with nme that works nicely cross platform https://github.com/RealyUniqueName/StablexNet

I am sure that a native extension could be written but I don't expect to see one anytime soon as its not so simple. If you want to take the challenge maybe you could look at writing an extension for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothServerSocket.html

Bluetooth is more generally used with bluetooth profiles and peripherals designed for them http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile.